# memory leak that occurred in a shell I wrote myself

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I have written a shell with C system programming.This shell receives comments connected successively with 20 pipes('|') and Decrypts them as child and parent processes.The code has no problems performing commands, but when I make a memory leak query with Valgrind, I see that a memory leak has occurred.Valgrind shows the reason for this as strdup, but even though I use free after strdup, the problem is not solved and memory leak continues to occur.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <signal.h>
#define MAX_LINE 1024 // The maximum length command
#define MAX_COMMAND 20 // Maximum number of commands in a single line
extern char* strdup(const char*);
void log_child_process(pid_t pid, char *command);

void execute_command(char *command, int in_fd, int out_fd) {
    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid == 0) {
        // Child process
        if (in_fd != 0) {
            dup2(in_fd, 0);
            close(in_fd);
        }
        if (out_fd != 1) {
            dup2(out_fd, 1);
            close(out_fd);
        }

        log_child_process(getpid(), command); 
        execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command, NULL);
        perror("execl");
        exit(1);
    } else if (pid < 0) {
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void signal_handler(int sig) {
    if (sig == SIGINT) {
        printf("\nYou can not exit with CTRL+C pressed. ':q' to exit.\n");
        printf("myshell> ");
        fflush(stdout);
    } else {
        printf("\nReceived signal %d, exiting.\n", sig);
        exit(0);
    }
}


void log_child_process(pid_t pid, char *command) {
    time_t rawtime;
    struct tm *timeinfo;
    char filename[80];
    char *file_extension = ".txt";

    time(&rawtime);
    timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

    strftime(filename, sizeof(filename), "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S", timeinfo);
    strcat(filename, file_extension);

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "a");
    if (file == NULL) {
        perror("Error opening log file");
        return;
    }

    fprintf(file, "PID: %d, Command: %s\n", pid, command);
    fclose(file);
}

char *strtrim(char *str) {
    char *end;

    // Trim leading space
    while (isspace(*str)) {
        str++;
    }

    if (*str == 0) {  // All spaces?
        return str;
    }

    // Trim trailing space
    end = str + strlen(str) - 1;
    while (end > str && isspace(*end)) {
        end--;
    }
    *(end + 1) = '\0';

    // Allocate new memory for trimmed string and copy it
    char *new_str = strdup(str);

    return new_str;
}

void split_commands(char *input, char **commands, int *num_commands) {
    int count = 0;
    const char delimiter[] = "|";
    char *token;
   
    // Count the number of commands
    for (int i = 0; input[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (input[i] == '|')
            count++;
    }
    *num_commands = count + 1;

    // Split input into commands
    token = strtok(input, delimiter);
    for (int i = 0; i < *num_commands; i++) {
        commands[i] = strtrim(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    }
}

void handle_redirections(char **command, int *in_fd, int *out_fd) {
    char *input_file = NULL;
    char *output_file = NULL;
    char *token;
    const char delimiter[] = " \t\n";

    char *cmd = strdup(*command);
    char *new_command = (char *) calloc(MAX_LINE, sizeof(char));

    token = strtok(cmd, delimiter);
    while (token != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(token, "<") == 0) {
            token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
            input_file = strdup(token);
        } else if (strcmp(token, ">") == 0) {
            token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
            output_file = strdup(token);
        } else {
            strcat(new_command, token);
            strcat(new_command, " ");
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    }

    *command = strtrim(new_command);

    if (input_file != NULL) {
        *in_fd = open(input_file, O_RDONLY);
        if (*in_fd < 0) {
            perror(input_file);
            exit(1);
        }
        free(input_file);
    }

    if (output_file != NULL) {
        *out_fd = open(output_file, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
        if (*out_fd < 0) {
            perror(output_file);
            exit(1);
        }
        free(output_file);
    }

    free(cmd);
    free(new_command);
}

int main(int argc , char *argv[]) {
if(argc > 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: gcc -o program_name program_name.c && ./program_name\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

char input[MAX_LINE];
char *commands[MAX_COMMAND];
int num_commands;

signal(SIGINT, signal_handler);

while (1) {
    printf("myshell> ");
    fflush(stdout);

    if (fgets(input, MAX_LINE, stdin) == NULL) {
        break;
    }
    // Remove trailing newline character
    input[strlen(input) - 1] = '\0';

    if (strcmp(input, ":q") == 0) {
        exit(0);
    }

    split_commands(input, commands, &num_commands);

    if(num_commands > MAX_COMMAND){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Single line can have maximum %d commands.\n", MAX_COMMAND);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int in_fd = 0;
    int out_fd = 1;
    int fd[2];

    for (int i = 0; i < num_commands; i++) {
        if (i < num_commands - 1) {
            if (pipe(fd) < 0) {
                perror("pipe");
                exit(1);
            }
            out_fd = fd[1];
        } else {
            out_fd = 1;
        }

        handle_redirections(&commands[i], &in_fd, &out_fd);

        execute_command(commands[i], in_fd, out_fd);

        if (in_fd != 0) {
            close(in_fd);
        }
        if (out_fd != 1) {
            close(out_fd);
        }
        in_fd = fd[0];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_commands; i++) {
        free(commands[i]);
        commands[i] = NULL; // added to avoid dangling pointer
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num_commands; i++) {
        wait(NULL);
    }

}
    /*for (int i = 0; i < num_commands; i++) {
    free(commands[i]);
}*/


return 0;
}
```

Valgrind result as follow :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rEt7P.png)

I am trying prevent memory leaks in code.

Comment: Scale back your code until the leak disappears. Perhaps even start over and add bit by bit (remembering to build with extra warnings enabled, treated as errors) and test before adding the bits, until the problem comes back. That will make it easier to isolate the code causing the problem and create a [mre] that you can [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Don't post pictures of text. Valgrind output is text. Post text as text.

Answer (score 0):

The lost thing was allocated by `strtrim` so it should be a `command`.

`handle_redirections` writes into `*command` without freeing what was there before.